# Using interface as Bounding Type in a Generic class

Tags: java

```
public class CollectionsOutput {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here



        //A.display(2,3);



    }

}
interface B
{

}
class A implements B
{

}
class C <T & B>
{

}
```

In above Java program I am getting compile error in class C declaration. ( as '>' expected) . But I think we can also specify interfaces also as bounding types in Generics, but it's not working. Please help me in this.

Comment: What were you hoping `T & B` would mean or represent?

Comment: I am restricting T as class implementing B.

Answer (score 4):

With generics and bounds, `&` is only used in between multiple bounds for a generic type parameter declaration.

If you meant that `T` has to be a subtype of `B`, then use `extends`:

```
class C<T extends B> {}
```

You might expect it to be something like this:

```
class C<T implements B> {}  // INCORRECT
```

because that's how you normally have a class implement an interface.

```
class Concrete implements AnInterface {}
```

But when specifying bounds for a generic type parameter, you must use `extends`, not `implements`.

Using `&` would be appropriate with multiple bounds, e.g.:

```
interface D {}
class C<T extends B & D> {}
```

Note that when using multiple bounds, any extra bounds beyond the first must be an interface type, not a class or another type variable.

Comment: Suppose if you want to have T as a class implementing D interface, what can be the syntax for it.

Comment: Similar to the one for `B`: `class C<T extends D>`.

Comment: But here T is a class and D is an interface, how can a class extends an interface

Comment: It's the way bounds work for generic type parameters -- use `extends` even if the bound is an interface.  Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You likely meant `<T extends B>` as a way to ensure that whatever type you passed as a generic was still attached to your marker interface.

Answer (score 0):

Intersection types `A & I & ...` are only allowed in constructs like `C extends A & I & ...` to specify more than one bound.

For example:

```
public class C<T extends Number & Serializable> {

}
```

This means that `C` is parameterized by some type that extends `Number` and implements `Cloneable` at the same time.

Another example:

```
public <T extends Number & Cloneable> void doSomething(T cloneableNumber) {

}
```

Here double restriction is applied to parameter type.

Your case does not use a type bound, so intersection type cannot be used.

Comment: Suppose if you want to have T as a class implementing D interface, what can be the syntax for it. –

Comment: I'm supposing that `T` you ask about is a type parameter. In this case it will be simply `class C<T extends D> { ... }`.